# Numpy String Encoding

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, numpy

The module numpy is an excellent tool for memory-efficient storage of python objects, among them strings. For ANSI strings in numpy arrays only 1 byte per character is used.

However, there is one inconvenience. The type of stored objects is no more `string` but `bytes`, which means that have to be decoded for further use in most cases, which in turn means quite bulky code:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> my_array = numpy.array(['apple', 'pear'], dtype = 'S5')
>>> print("Mary has an {} and a {}".format(my_array[0], my_array[1]))
Mary has an b'apple' and a b'pear'
>>> print("Mary has an {} and a {}".format(my_array[0].decode('utf-8'),
... my_array[1].decode('utf-8')))
Mary has an apple and a pear
```

This inconvenience can be eliminated by using another data type, e.g:

```
>>> my_array = numpy.array(['apple', 'pear'], dtype = 'U5')
>>> print("Mary has an {} and a {}".format(my_array[0], my_array[1]))
Mary has an apple and a pear
```

However, this is achieved only by cost of 4-fold increase in memory usage:

```
>>> numpy.info(my_array)
class:  ndarray
shape:  (2,)
strides:  (20,)
```

```
itemsize:  20
```

```
aligned:  True
contiguous:  True
fortran:  True
data pointer: 0x1a5b020
byteorder:  little
byteswap:  False
type: <U5
```

Is there a solution that combines advantages of both efficient memory allocation and convenient usage for ANSI strings?

Comment: This is a Python3 issue, which displays byte strings with the `b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a big difference over the `decode`, but `astype` works (and can be applied to the whole array rather than each string).  But the longer array will remain around as long as it is needed.

```
In [538]: x=my_array.astype('U');"Mary has an {} and a {}".format(x[0],x[1])
Out[538]: 'Mary has an apple and a pear'
```

I can't find anything in the `format` syntax that would force 'b' less formatting.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19864787/901925
- shows how to customize the Formatter class, changing the `format_field` method.  I tried something similar with the `convert_field` method.  But the calling syntax is still messy.

```
In [562]: def makeU(astr):
    return astr.decode('utf-8')
   .....: 

In [563]: class MyFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def convert_field(self, value, conversion):
        if 'q'== conversion:
            return makeU(value)
        else:
            return super(MyFormatter, self).convert_field(value, conversion)
   .....:         

In [564]: MyFormatter().format("Mary has an {!q} and a {!q}",my_array[0],my_array[1])
Out[564]: 'Mary has an apple and a pear'
```

---

A couple of other ways of doing this formatting:

```
In [642]: "Mary has an {1} and a {0} or {1}".format(*my_array.astype('U'))
Out[642]: 'Mary has an pear and a apple or pear'
```

This converts the array (on the fly) and passes it to `format` as a list.  It also works if the array is already unicode:

```
In [643]: "Mary has an {1} and a {0} or {1}".format(*uarray.astype('U'))
Out[643]: 'Mary has an pear and a apple or pear'
```

`np.char` has functions that apply string functions to elements of a character array.  With this `decode` can be applied to the whole array:

```
In [644]: "Mary has a {1} and an {0}".format(*np.char.decode(my_array))
Out[644]: 'Mary has a pear and an apple'
```

(this doesn't work if the array is already unicode).

If you do much with string arrays, `np.char` is worth a study.

Comment: Thank you for the profound answer. As I need not only format strings, but also pass single array elements to functions, I opted for making the function: `def U(astr): return astr.decode('utf-8')`, as it requires minimum additional symbols. It is also the most obvious solution.

Answer (score 4):

Given:

```
>>> my_array = numpy.array(['apple', 'pear'], dtype = 'S5')
```

You can decode on the fly:

```
>>> print("Mary has an {} and a {}".format(*map(lambda b: b.decode('utf-8'), my_array)))
Mary has an apple and a pear
```

Or you can create a specific formatter:

```
import string
class ByteFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, decoder='utf-8'):
        self.decoder=decoder

    def format_field(self, value, spec):
        if isinstance(value, bytes):
            return value.decode(self.decoder)
        return super(ByteFormatter, self).format_field(value, spec)   

>>> print(ByteFormatter().format("Mary has an {} and a {}", *my_array))
Mary has an apple and a pear
```