# How to format percentage point differences in Python?

Tags: python

I have to present the difference between two percentages using Python. For example, the difference between 40% and 41.234% is 1.234 percentage points, or 1.234 pp.

If I wanted to format the increase as a percentage, I would use the format specifier `{:.0%}`:

```
increase = 0.01234

"{:+.3%} ".format(increase)
>>> "+1.234 %"
```

### What I'm looking for

A format specifier that replaces the `%` with `pp`, like this:

```
"{some_specifier} ".format(increase)
>>> "+1.234 pp"
```

### What I'm not looking for

I know that I could use f-strings like this

```
f"{increase * 100:+.3f} pp"
>>> "+1.234 pp"
```

but I'm specifically looking for a format specifier that I can use with `.format()`.

### Edit

I realised that a little bit of background may be useful here. In my implementation, the `increase` can represent a normal float, integer, percentage or percentage point. In order to get the right representation, I have use a variable-format mapping that looks something like:

```
format_mapping = {
    "var_x": "{:,.0f}",    # for large numbers
    "var_y": "{:+.3f}",    # for small numbers
    "var_z": "{:.4%}",     # for percentages
}
```

The variable names represent the column names of a pandas dataframe `my_data`, so that I can then apply the formatting to those columns, for the sake of reporting

```
for var in my_data.columns:
    fmt = format_mapping[var]
    my_data[var] = pd.Series(fmt.format(value) for value in my_data[var])
```

Comment: Have you considered just doing `"{:+.3%} ".format(increase).replace('%', 'pp')` instead of trying to make the f-string output 'pp' itself?

Comment: That's a nice idea. I have a situation, though, where I have different variable types (percentages, floats, integers) that can be used as input for `increase`. I currently use a dictionary mapping between variable-types and format-specifiers to get the format I'm looking for. The format-specifier can then just be used without actually changing the `"{format_specifier}.format(value)"` syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare custom formatter and replace `"%"` with `"pp"` by overriding [`Formatter.format_field()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format_field) method:

```
from string import Formatter    

class MyFormatter(Formatter):
    def format_field(self, value, spec):
        if spec.endswith("p"):
            return super(MyFormatter, self).format_field(value, spec[:-1] + "%")[:-1] + "pp"
        else:
            return super(MyFormatter, self).format_field(value, spec)
```

Usage:

```
print(MyFormatter().format("%: {0:+.3%}; pp: {0:+.3p}", 0.01234))
```

P.S. In python 3 you can use `super()` without arguments.

Answer (score 2):

There are maybe things you can do with [inline pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026423/python-string-format-with-inline-pipes) and subclassing a `Format` class, but in this case I think it might be easier to just write functions to handle it:

```
def pct(num, digits=0):
    return '{:+.{}} pp'.format(num * 100, digits)

...

f"{pct(increase, 4)}"
# '+1.234 pp'
```

you can then put all those functions in their own file, if you want, and invoke them by just calling them in f-strings.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
increase = 0.01234

print("{:+.4} {}".format(increase*100, "pp"))
```

Result:

```
+1.234 pp
```

Comment: This isn't what OP asked for. They want the same output, but with `0.01234` as the input instead of `1.234`

Comment: You conveniently changed the value of `increase`

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I edited the answer to have the same input.