# Is there a way to set the default float presentation for Python "{:5.3e}".format(a) if a=None and is not a float?

Tags: python, string-formatting

Is there an easy way to set the default float presentation for Python's format command:

```
"{:5.3e}".format(a)
```

so that if the variable a has a value of None instead of a float, some default like 5 spaces might be printed?

The format string can be include many fields and is given by a user.
The values in a are calculated internally.

Comment: You could write a custom formatter which performs this test, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864302/add-custom-conversion-types-for-string-formatting

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like

```
print("{:.3e}".format(a)) if a else print(" "*5).
```

you don't need `5.3e` since in scientific notation you always get 5 digits because of .3e. Except you want to shift the whole text to the right. Then you could use `{:>10.3e}`.